# Right Panel in android emulator 3.0 not showing up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, android-studio-2.0

I am getting some problem in opening the right side panel of android emulator 3.0 
This is what i want:

[image]

and i am getting this.

[image]

I have just now updated my Android Studio to 2.0 Stable version.
Can somebody help me on this.. I am bit new in Android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513249/android-emulator-missing-right-panel/36517049#36517049

Comment: @TheDarkKnight.. The controls are there now.. but the emulator is taking too much time to open.. it has not open once after the update..:(.. any clue  why??

Answer (score 1):

I just tried first "How can I hide Right Panel :P"

I have just clicked on Minimize button to Hide it...

[image]

Now as you want to display it again. I just clicked on **Maximize Button** (**Left Top Corner**) in Emulator Screen.

[image]

and I found Right Panel again.

[image]

**Try it... It will be Helpful to you.**

Comment: my Maximize Button is disabled.. only minimize and close button are working