# Android Emulator: missing right panel

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-2.0

It seems to be that in the latest version of Android studio, Google includes a new skin for the emulator.

[image]

I noticed that their is a side panel at the right of the emulator. In my case, this panel is missing. I've searched for hours but with no result. Could anyone show me how to enable this panel in the emulator

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Just answered : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36513449/1318946

Comment: @PratikButani That did not work for me. I'm using Android Studio 2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04, there is no maximize button to press.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some hours digging, I ended up updating my Android sdk tools to the latest version (25.1.1 in my case). Then the problem solved.

Answer (score 13):

1. Put mouse at top right conner(Cursor change to double head arrow)
2. left click mouse and drag out to right.
   The panel will display again.

Answer (score 8):

Minimise the emulator window then maximise it again. The right panel will re-appear.

Comment: what a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I might late to answer this question but hope it will help someone :

If you want side panel of android emulator just resize using mouse and side panel will be visible. I have tried this and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

For my case, the right pane suddenly disappeared. Unfortunately, none of the above solutions worked.

Below steps helped me to get the side panel back:

1. Close the emulator
2. Reopen it using cold boot

**Note**:

While you can cold boot from Android Studio, I used a command line then.

On Windows, it looks like this. This may change depends on OS.

```
cd C:/Users/{userName}/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/emulator
./emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_29 -no-snapshot -no-snapshot-load
```