# Android emulator no toolbar

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2 but whenever I launch an emulator there's no toolbar and I can't resize it.

I want to be able to resize and show the toolbar like the image below:

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize the AVD emulator in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737499/how-to-resize-the-avd-emulator-in-android-studio)

Comment: Hi @RohanKhude, I've edited my question.

Comment: solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53454944/438727

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a unexpected problem, try new device to fix .

But you can set scale type with 'AUTO' in emulator profile setting.

you can drag border of emulator to scale it.

Comment: I've edited my question, it's related to the emulator not to an android app.